# Type checking a custom object in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

I have the following object:

```
var car = {
  doors: 4
  wheels: 4
}
```

This is used in many files, is there a way that it can be checked easily across the entire codebase?

```
function insertCar(car) {
  if (!isCar(car)) {
    console.log('not a car')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, [instaceof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) will be the answer.
You can do something like this:

```
function Car(make, model, year) {
  this.make = make;
  this.model = model;
  this.year = year;
}
var mycar = new Car('Honda', 'Accord', 1998);
var a = mycar instanceof Car;    // returns true
var b = mycar instanceof Object; // returns true
```

As for [exporting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) and [importing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import), you need to define your object in one file and export it:

```
module.exports = function Car(make, model, year) {
 //...
}
```

Then you import it in whichever file you want with

```
import Car from 'components/car'
```

where `components/car` is an example of your file where object `Car` is exported from, in this case `Car.js` which is located in directory `components`.

Comment: great, thanks! Is it possible for ```instanceof Car``` to be used across files?

Comment: Read about [export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) and [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

Comment: @timothyylim I added now how you can export and import it. I hope it helps you.